# Python GEKKO: How to avoid raising an error from IPOPT "Solved to Acceptable Level."

Tags: python, gekko

I am solving a set of equations in simulation (IMODE = 1, SOLVER = 3). The IPOPT solver solves to an acceptable level and exits, but gekko returns an error for this and does return my solution. Per the IPOPT documentation, the tolerance for the acceptable level is 1.0e-6, which is the same as the default values for OTOL and RTOL used by gekko (and the values I am using). I was able to modify the gekko.py source code to get my answer to return, but by doing so I've bypassed all types of errors. I don't want all errors bypassed as they obviously help debugging other issues like infeasibilities. Is there a m.solve option that I am missing, or another way to not trigger an error when IPOPT solves to an acceptable level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle errors from a solver is to wrap the solve command in `try`, `except` statements. The [APPINFO](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmAppinfo) output may give you guidance on what type of error was encountered and let you respond differently to "infeasible solution", "solved to acceptable level", or [other IPOPT error codes](https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node36.html).

```py
try:
   m.solve(disp=True)
except:
   print('Solver error, looking at APPINFO')
   if m.options.APPINFO==1:
      print('APPINFO=1')
   elif m.options.APPINFO==2:
      print('APPINFO=2')
```

Another option is to [try a different solver such as APOPT or BPOPT](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver).

```
m.options.SOLVER = 1
```

**Edit:** The parameter `APPINFO` isn't updated when Gekko raises a solver exception. Try the following instead with `debug=0`:

```py
m.solve(disp=True,debug=0)
if m.options.APPINFO!=0:
   print('Solver error, looking at APPINFO')
if m.options.APPINFO==1:
   print('APPINFO=1')
elif m.options.APPINFO==2:
   print('APPINFO=2')
```

I just updated Gekko so that remote solves will also by-pass the raised exceptions and finish processing the options file with the `APPINFO` information. The `APPINFO` information is in `options.json` in the run directory when running locally and is read in with `load_JSON` in `gk_post_solve.py`.

Comment: When I run your appinfo script, the solver is still returning an APPINFO of 0. Any idea why the solver would be raising an exception but not assigning a value to the APPINFO? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It isn't getting to the point where it updates APPINFO. Can you try `m.solve(disp=True,debug=0)`. I'll edit my answer.